# How to style the border of the ListItemButton when selected in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, button, material-ui, listitem

I have the functionality where if the ListItemButton is selected, it will highlight it with a given background color. But now I want to style the ListItemButton even more by adding an outline or border color around it when selected. I used the attribute borderColor but currently it is not working.

[image: Button but not border or outline style when selected]

Source code:

```
 /* eslint-disable react/react-in-jsx-scope -- Unaware of jsxImportSource */
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import { useState } from "react";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import { css } from "@emotion/react";


export default function TestSample() {
  

  const [selected2, setSelected2] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ListItemButton
        sx={{
          "&.Mui-selected": {
            backgroundColor: "#02A7DD",
            borderColor: "red",
          },
          "&.Mui-focusVisible": {
            backgroundColor: "#02A7DD",
            borderColor: "red",
          },
          ":hover": {
            backgroundColor: "#02A7DD",
            borderColor: "red",
          },
        }}
        selected={selected2}
        onClick={() => setSelected2((prev) => !prev)}
      >
       ListItemButton
      </ListItemButton>

      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hoping for your responses as this would help me a lot especially since I am exploring MUI at the moment an trying to understand its use and implementation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the borderWidth and borderStyle properties. Right now you have a red border that is invisible and 0 pixels thick.

As a shorthand you can specify just the border property instead, for example:

```js
sx={{
    border: '1px solid red'
}}
```

which is the same as

```js
sx={{
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: '1px',
    borderColor: 'red'
}}
```

Comment: Oh I see, I should state its style and width rather than its color only. It's all clear now and will definitely use the shorthand version above.

Tried it recently and it worked! Thank you very much for your quick response and suggestion.